# How to negate invalid order data?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have an interesting order history table like this: if a user cancels an order, the system does not update the original order, but a new order would be input with a negative qty and negative cost on the same date, like:

```
user_id  date        qty    cost
1        2018-10-01   2    100.00  -- a wrong order
1        2018-10-01  -2   -100.00  -- negate the above order
1        2018-10-01   2    100.00  -- this is a valid order
1        2018-10-01   3    150.00  -- this is a valid order
1        2018-10-01   1     50.00  -- this is a valid order
```

How can I create a clean up table contain only valid order like:

```
user_id  date        qty    cost
1        2018-10-01   2    100.00 
1        2018-10-01   3    150.00
1        2018-10-01   1     50.00
```

I tried to use group by date, but that is not good because it might squash multiple valid orders in one day.

It would be very convenient if anyone can help me do this directly in sql server! Otherwise, I just write a python script to load data out and do this externally...

Comment: You have an order table with no `OrderNumber` field?

Comment: No OrderNumber exist. If I have anything like that, there won't be any problems...

Comment: How does the system distinguish the first row listed above from the third row listed?

Comment: each row has a different row id.

Comment: None of these rows have different IDs

Comment: Sorry I didn't include the IDs, the above table is just a miminal sample to illustrate my problem.

Comment: Perhaps a little _too_ minimal. :) I think Gordon's answer still works, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not a good design.  You really need an `order_id`.  The naive solution is `not exists`:

```
select o.*
from orders o
where not exists (select 1 from orders o2 where o2.user_id = o.user_id and o2.date = o.date and o2.qty = - o.qty and o2.cost = - o.cost);
```

Alas, someone could order twice in one day and then cancel only one of them.  So, you need counter.  So, use `row_number()`:

```
with o as (
      select o.*,
             row_number() over (partition by user_id, date, qty, cost order by user_id) as seqnum
      from orders o
     )
select o.*
from o
    where not exists (select 1
                      from orders o2
                      where o2.user_id = o.user_id and o2.date = o.date o2.seqnum = o.seqnum and
                            o2.qty = - o.qty and o2.cost = - o.cost
                     );
```